# Return Class based view from function based view

Tags: python, django

So I set up a login view, and upon successful login I'd like to go to a page of my choice by referencing another class based view. I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this.

Login view

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            #Not sure what to do next
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request, Dashboard))?   
        else:
            #TODO
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
```

Dashboard class I'm trying to get to

```
class Dashboard(ListView):
    model = models.Note
    template_name = 'notemanager/dashboard.html'

    def get_context_data(self, request,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        notedata = models.Note.objects.filter(added_by = User)
        reminderdata = models.Reminder.objects.filter(added_by = User)
        context['notes'] = notedata
        context['reminder'] = reminderdata

        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',views.Login.as_view(),name="login"),
    path('',views.Dashboard.as_view(), name ="dash")

]
```

Comment: You redirect to URLs, not views. Show your URL patterns.

Comment: We'll need to see you `urls.py` where you assign a route to `Dashboard` to help.

Comment: I included my urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the way to redirect is by using the name of the url/route for the view you are using.

So if in your `urls.py` you had something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^dashboard$', Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
]
```

You could reuse the `name` part of the route to send the user a 302 redirect using [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            #Not sure what to do next
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request, Dashboard))?   
            return redirect('dashboard')  # matches the name part of the route in urls.py
        else:
            #TODO
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
```

---

n.b., you also have an error in your view.  There is no `request` parameter to `get_context_data`, so it should look like:

```
class Dashboard(ListView):
    model = models.Note
    template_name = 'notemanager/dashboard.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        notedata = models.Note.objects.filter(added_by = User)
        reminderdata = models.Reminder.objects.filter(added_by = User)
        context['notes'] = notedata
        context['reminder'] = reminderdata

        return context
```

Comment: Okay that works but now I get `get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an explanation of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Stupid error if you ask me, but at least I know now that when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on self; as well as the request (self.request) this includes the positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured according to the URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

Add redirect in your views.py,

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form =AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user=form.get_user()
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('dash') #If you have mentioned app_name in urls.py add app_name:dash in place of dash    
    else:
        #TODO
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
```

In urls.py you have,

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('login/',views.Login.as_view(),name="login"),
     path('',views.Dashboard.as_view(), name ="dash"),
]
```

This will redirect users to 127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: Okay that works but now I get `get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: Remove request from get_context_data()